# XML String Converted to Date/Time timestamp

Tags: php, xml, strtotime

**Real quick question:**

I have an XML file with a "Time" attribute. I am calling this XML into my PHP and giving it the variable $game_time.

An example value for the attribute is "8:30 PM"...

Since it is coming from XML, it is reading "8:30 PM" as a string.

Now my question, how can I convert this string to an actual timestamp?

I think I need to use strtotime somehow, but can't get the syntax right...

I am wanting this XML time to be converted to a timestamp because I am eventually going to compare this time with the server's time and shoot out a conditional output...

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks,
John

Comment: Either I did not explain this very well or everyone hates me.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() should be able to convert something like "8:30 PM" to a Unix timestamp:

```
$time = strtotime("8:30 PM");
```

Now $time will contain the timestamp.  Note that strtotime will assume the server day/month/year since you didn't specify a date, only a time.  If you're comparing only to the server time and not the server date, you can grab the individual components of a timestamp using getdate():

```
$timeArray = getdate($time);
echo $timeArray['seconds'];
```